# Can't use Scrapy after launching someone's project: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, modulenotfounderror

I was working on scrapy and received project (let's name it "alien_project") from other developer, after launching it I've faced scrapy problems. My old projects works and completes but when I try to create new projects error appears, seems like it tries to start from that "alien_project". Here's error I get in terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 125, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 71, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority="project")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 323, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alien_project'
```

I already tried to reinstall Python. I also get this error working in virtual environmet. Didn't find somethins suspicious in that project, maybe it's just an coincedence, but Scrapy always refers to that "alien_project" project.

`I'm using: Windows 11 | Scrapy 2.9.0. | Python 3.10.9`

Comment: How are you running the crawler?

Comment: @911 via terminal in project folder with scrapy.cfg 'scrapy crawl class_name'

Comment: Have you checked the "SPIDER_MODULES" configuration in "settings" and your directory name

Comment: @911 yes I did, didn't find anything suspicious there. Just common scrapy files

Comment: @Сергей Кох unfortunately that's all what I have, I don't know why this trouble appeared. I used to work with a lot of scrapy projects, did everything as usual. I didn't update anything. My mistake that I didn't use venv

Comment: Look in all the spider files in the "alien_project" and make sure there is no code being executed in the global scope.  Such as calls to `CrawlerProcess` or `CrawlerRunner`

Comment: @Alexander didn't find anything there, spiders are very common and settings are default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and solved it. Somehow there's was copy of scrapy.cfg of 'alien_project' above all my project folder. I guess Scrapy tried to refer to that scrapy config file. I just removed it and know everything works.

Thanks for all people trying to help me!